# txt file to 2d charArray

Tags: java

I have a .txt file which a I want to convert into a 2d array of chars. The only error I get is that linea.toCharArray(); cannot be converted into a 2d array

```
public static char[][] llegeixPuzle(String nomPuzle)throws IOException{
    BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nomPuzle));
    String linea = "";
    char[][] 2dBoard = new char[0][0];
    while((linea = input.readLine()) != null){
           2dBoard  = linea.toCharArray();
    }
   return 2dBoard;
}
```

My .txt file contains the following

```
 TCADRACT
 PPPPPPPP
 ········
 ········
 ········
 ········
 pppppppp
 tcadract
```

Comment: Because `.toCharArray()` returns one dimensional array, and you're assigning it to the `char[][]`, which is two-dimensional array type. Also, `.toCharArray()` will just dismantle your string into the characters.. better to include your input text format and the desired output, what you want to have.

Comment: You have to tell us what does this file contain also.

Comment: Sorry about that @Typhon I just added what the .txt file contains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to count your `rows`and `column`, basically you have 8 rows and 8 columns.
So first we have created the `char [][]` array so that we will save our data

```
 int totalRows = 8;
int totalColumn = 8;
char[][] myArray = new char[totalRows][totalColumn];
```

Creating the file that we will read

```
  File file = new File(nomPuzle);
```

Starting with the try-catch construct we iterate through our file for every iteration we create a new `char[] chars` array after that we iterate through the `chars[]` array and we add our data to our array  `myArray[i][j] = chars[j];`

```
 try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {  //try with resources
          for (int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine() && i < totalRows; i++) {
              char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
              for (int j = 0; j < totalColumn && j < chars.length; j++) {
                  myArray[i][j] = chars[j];
              }
          }
      }
```

FULL CODE

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {



     char [][] returnedArray =  llegeixPuzle("YOURFILE.TXT");
     
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(returnedArray));



    }
    public static char[][] llegeixPuzle(String nomPuzle)throws IOException {

        int totalRows = 8;
        int totalColumn = 8;
        char[][] myArray = new char[totalRows][totalColumn];

        File file = new File(nomPuzle);
      try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {  //try with resources
          for (int i = 0; scanner.hasNextLine() && i < totalRows; i++) {
              char[] chars = scanner.nextLine().toCharArray();
              for (int j = 0; j < totalColumn && j < chars.length; j++) {
                  myArray[i][j] = chars[j];
              }
          }
      }

        return myArray;
    }

}
```

OUTPUT

```
[[T, C, A, D, R, A, C, T], [P, P, P, P, P, P, P, P], [·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·], [·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·], [·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·], [·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·, ·], [p, p, p, p, p, p, p, p], [t, c, a, d, r, a, c, t]]
```